# Put mysql data into array, search for a matching value, and pull out a corresponding value

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, mysqli

I am trying to create a script that pull data with php from mysql, and puts everything into an array. This was successul.

What I am trying to figure out, is how to match a value against the entire array, and then pull out a corresponding value.

**For example I have:**

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM `addrbook`";
$res = $mysqli->query($q) or trigger_error($mysqli->error."[$q]");
$array = array(); // initialize
while($row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
$array[] = array(
'key' => $row[0],
'username' => $row[1],
'password' => $row[2],
'dogeaddr' => $row[3],
'google'   => $row[4],
'facebook' => $row[5],
'twitter'  => $row[6],
'linkedin' => $row[7],
'youtube'  => $row[8]
);
$match = array_search("facebookuser", $array);
if ($match !== FALSE) {
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($match);
}
$res->free();
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

**CURRENT Code:**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1);
include '../db/dbcon.php';
$thekey = $_GET['facebook'];
$facebook = $mysqli->real_escape_string($thekey);
if($_GET) {
$q = "SELECT * FROM `addrbook` WHERE `facebook` = " . $facebook;
} else {
//$q = "SELECT * FROM `addrbook`";
echo 'The key to the kingdom, is incorrect.';
}
//Start connection with SQL
$res = $mysqli->query($q) or trigger_error($mysqli->error."[$q]");
//$array = array(); // initialize
while($row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($row['dogeaddr']);
}
$res->free();
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

CURRENT CODE - 7:26 MST, USA

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "shooleyb_user", "access2012", "shooleyb_altcend");
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT *FROM `addrbook`");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row['google'];
}
?>
```

Note: Putting in the facebook === portion gave it a white screen with the google has no index issue

**My database:**

```
addrbook:
key
user
password
addr
google
facebook
twitter
linkedin
youtube
```

**Sample row for testing:**

201402041741    user1   password    123456789   google  fbboy   twitboy linkboy youtubeboy

I would like to find any facebook user in the array (this will later be a variable from a form), and then be able to pull out that facebook user's google in the same sql row. Lastly, I want to encode the result (the corresponding google data) to JSON.

Does anybody know how this can be done, and or if my code is just wrong?
Thank you for any help in advance. This is very appreciated.

Comment: why search every field for "facebookuser" you must know which de field this is in. and why search  the array, rather than the db?

Comment: facebookuser is an example of a facebook username that would for example, be in one of the rows, for various users, in the facebook column. I would be happy to search the DB. But I wasn't able to figure out a way to make a mysql query to search all of the "Facebook" column for said value, and pull out corresponding "google" value for said user.

Comment: post your db schema and a sample row, should be easy

Comment: Structure your Query to pull out the data, that way you are not reading through the whole table for matching pairs.

Comment: @Pogrindis I tried this, and wasn't successful.

Comment: `SELECT google from addrbook where facebook='fbboy' `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok now the right way,

Change your query $q, to this:

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM addrbook WHERE facebook='" . $FACEBOOKNAME . "'";
```

Then you will only get MySQL rows where facebook is equal to $FACEBOOK name, whatever it may be.  Now that MySQL already made sure facebook name is equal, you just get the value you want, in this case google.

```
while($row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($row['google']);
}
```

Not really sure what is going on incorrectly, but this is EXACTLY how I would format my code:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM addrbook WHERE facebook='" . $_GET['facebook']. "'");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['google'];
}
```

If I weere you I would try this EXACT CODE with your connection info before attempting changes to make it fit your needs

SLOPPY CODE

```
$con = mysqli_connect("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM addrbook");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    if ($row['facebook'] === $_GET['facebook']) {
        echo $row['google'];
    }
}
```

If that doesn't work I really don't know

Comment: What would $key be? I feel like I should know this.. Is that the google value?

Comment: the foreach loop works like [this](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) the $key I guess is unecesary it is just the key for that value in the array. So in your array, "facebook" is the key for $row[5] (Which is the $value).

Comment: The array isn't necessarily "facebook" its just an array with many values, that I want to find a value in the facebook portion for the user, and then pull out the google value for the user. Does that make a little more sense?

Comment: Soooooo Much more sense, to clarify you know the Facebook name and you want the google name?

Comment: Correct. For the same user.

Comment: It almost worked. When I try to give it a variable in POST, it gives me the php error:

Comment: Notice: Unknown column 'fbboy' in 'where clause'[SELECT * FROM `addrbook` WHERE facebook=fbboy] and Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object

Comment: Ok can you post your code somewhere? Seems like a little mistake in the code.

Comment: @Superfunnytogo you need to quote the string variable in your query

Comment: @Dagon Ahhh thanks forgot that, Post edited, make the change to your query as I have in original post

Comment: So if I POST http://altcend.com/api/core/social2.php?facebook=facebook then I get back all corresponding google values. I am trying to get the google value for the facebook user value that I put in.

Comment: [04-Feb-2014 19:10:38 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in social2.php on line 4 returned in your EXACT code (besides my db values)

Comment: This means that there was no MySQL record where facebook equalled what the $_GET was, try the section in my edited post labeled "sloppy code"

Comment: Whoops just saw a mistake I made, I used new mysqli();  When it should have been mysqli_connect();  it has been fixed in the post so the first method might work.

Comment: AHHhhhhhhhh! lol this is crazy, That error is a step in the right direction though.  That error means that there is no column named google, are you sure it exists?

Comment: Yes. So I am going to post the code above that I have "working" -- almost. When I do ?facebook=fbboy, I get all records in the table for google back. I am trying to get the corresponding row's google value. Almost there! -- EDIT: NEW CODE POSTED for 7:26 MST,USA

Comment: You are missing a space between "*" and "FROM", you need the if facebook thing to sort out the Google values you don't want,  Try my original full EXACT solution again now that I have fixed some of my code, and if you can double chack that there is a column named google

Comment: Tried the exact code and got a blank white screen with no errors in the log.

Comment: Got it, your 'addrbook' needed to be `. Got to love syntax.

Comment: OMG (Usher), I am going to figure it out if it's the last thing I do.  I am going to go setup a test MySQL databse and JsFiddle so we can look at the same info so there is no confusion, give me one minute.  I have a feeling we are missing something very small that is causing all of these problems.  Also thanks @Dagon.

Comment: actully better not to use either quotes around a table name you only need smart quotes if its a reserved word.

Comment: Ok nevermind Ignore that comment and congratulations!  sorry I should have seen that little mistake.